# Convert row to column in SQL Server does not work?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot

```
period  providerid  type    volume     subscribers
--------------------------------------------------
Aug-2016    7        1      4027917    117172
Aug-2016    7        2      5325430    232293
Aug-2016    7        3      8722165    236472
Jul-2016    7        1      2981655     97409
Jul-2016    7        2      6449570    147315
Jul-2016    7        3      7702484    206140
```

I want my result in this format.

```
period      providerid  SMS     Data    minutes
Aug-2016    7           432142  42342   5454
Jul-2016    7           5454    5454    545
```

I have tried this query but it does not work.

```
select   
    period, providerid, 1 as SMS, 2 as Data, 3 as minutes
from 
    #P         
pivot
    (sum(volume) for [type] in ([1],[2],[3])) as P
```

Please help me in SQL server

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Get rid of `subscribers` column:

```
SELECT  [period],
        providerid, 
        [1] as SMS, 
        [2] as [Data], 
        [3] as [minutes]
FROM (
    SELECT [period],providerid, [type], volume
    FROM YourTable         
) as t
PIVOT (
    MAX(volume) FOR [type] in ([1], [2], [3]) 
) as P
```

Output:

```
period      providerid  SMS     Data    minutes
Aug-2016    7           4027917 5325430 8722165
Jul-2016    7           2981655 6449570 7702484
```

Answer (score 3):

When you use `1 AS SMS` it reads `1` as the number 1. Instead you should tell it that you mean the column i.e. `[1]`.
Also I'm not too sure how the column `subscribers` is used, so when you are pivoting you might want to remove it.

I.e. Try;

```
select   period,providerid,[1] as SMS,[2] as Data,[3] as minutes
FROM   (SELECT Period, ProviderID, Type, Volume 
       FROM #P) X         
PIVOT(
   sum(volume)
   FOR [type] in ([1],[2],[3]) 
)as P
```

Answer (score 2):

Your query would probably work if you use column names instead of constants:

```
SELECT period, providerid, [1] as SMS, [2] as Data, [3] as minutes
FROM #P         
PIVOT (sum(volume)
       FOR [type] in ([1], [2], [3]) 
      ) as P;
```

That said, I usually prefer to write these as conditional aggregations:

```
select period,
       sum(case when [type] = 1 then volume end) as SMS,
       sum(case when [type] = 2 then volume end) as data,
       sum(case when [type] = 3 then volume end) as minutes
from #p
group by period;
```

Comment: by using first query i am getting this result....................................................

Comment: Aug-2016 7 4027917 NULL NULL
Aug-2016 7 NULL 5325430 NULL
Aug-2016 7 NULL NULL 8722165
Jul-2016 7 2981655 NULL NULL
Jul-2016 7 NULL 6449570 NULL
Jul-2016 7 NULL NULL 7702484